# Why does Let's Encrypt pick up disabled sites?

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, lets-encrypt

If I run `letsencrypt --apache`, it will fail, complaining that five domains on my small server fail due to timeouts. However, all five domains are disabled (`a2dissite fake.example.net`). Why is Let's Encrypt even trying to protect them in the first place? (Is this a bug?) Is there any way I can tell it to skip disabled sites, instead of having to deselect them by hand?

Apache on Ubuntu Server 16.04.3 LTS (xenial).

Comment: `a2dissite` is a non-standard, slightly helpful tool the Ubuntu folks bundle with their particular Apache distribution. It's not a stock part of Apache, and for that reason, it's a little silly to expect Let's Encrypt to care about it.

Comment: I replaced `letsencrypt` (from the repos) with `certbot` (from a PPA) for different reasons (support of IDN domains), and it also skipped the disabled sites (`certbot --apache` has a less fancy interface, but works a charm). So this is no longer a problem.

Comment: a2ensite/a2dissite is a common way of making/removing symlinks to configurations. When symlinks are removed, the sites shouldn't be visible to letsencrypt, it must be looking in the entire /etc/apache2 tree, not only what's referenced from apache.conf and includes.

Comment: @Lenne. Found the actual answer: it wasn't looking in the entire Apache2 tree. There were some symlinks still present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you initially run letsencrypt (or certbot), it creates a new config file for each site configured and enabled on the server. This means `example.net.conf` is supplemented with `example.net-le-ssl.conf`. If you wish to disable a site, you now need to disable *both* config files.

```
a2dissite example.net
a2dissite example.net-le-ssl
```

(Optionally add `.conf` at the end of both the above: it makes no difference.)

If you fail to do this, letsencypt will still attempt to renew the SSL certificate for the site in question.